# How to resize images in Lightroom to a particular file size?

Tags: lightroom, file-size, presets

How would I create a preset to export files to a given file size?  I need to be able to export a 2mb file for a realtor.

Answer (score 5):

On the export dialog, set your image sizing (I set mine as you requested).
[image]

Then click the add button in the bottom left hand corner of the dialog.
[image]

Set its name
[image]

And you are all set.

Comment: Just above where you showed under File settings, you can limit the size to 2mb!

Comment: Oops I meant to set do it that way. I will edit -- thanks

Comment: I had to move the setting "limit file size to"  3000k

Comment: ..And also changed "resize to fit" to 3.0 megapixels to get a 2MB file! Not sure why the 2000k / 2.0 MB came out to 1.5MB file.

Comment: @Zoe - Compression. Most 3MP files will be considerably smaller than 3MB. How much the file can be compressed at any given setting is also content dependent. the more pixels in the image that have the same values, the smaller it will compress.